# Postgresql Connection Error tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused

Tags: postgresql, tcp, elixir, phoenix-framework, nanoboxio

I'm playing around with Nanobox for the first time, trying to launch an Elixir app.  I have been able to run the app locally ok, but I'm failing with launching a 'dry-run' with `nanobox deploy dry-run`and I get the following error:

```
! FAILED TO BEFORE_LIVE1: MIX ECTO.CREATE --QUIET !

    Exit
     1

    Command
     su - gonano -c "cd /app; siphon --prefix '' -- bash -i -l -c \"mix ecto.create --quiet\""

    Output

     07:43:15.795 [error] GenServer #PID<0.189.0> terminating
     ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
         (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
         (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
         (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
     Last message: nil
     ** (Mix) The database for Codsonline.Repo couldn't be created: an exception was raised:
         ** (DBConnection.ConnectionError) tcp connect (localhost:5432): connection refused - :econnrefused
             (db_connection) lib/db_connection/connection.ex:148: DBConnection.Connection.connect/2
             (connection) lib/connection.ex:622: Connection.enter_connect/5
             (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3


Error   : failed to execute hook (before_live) on e528aa7c36b4da40466b9d1d81154f3cbbcb785a278e8435dd20e71eb7f1974c: util:Exec:/opt/nanobox/hooks/before_live: bad exit code(1):
Context : failed to finalize deploy -> failed to run before deploy hooks
```

I had no issues when originally running `mix ecto.create`.

`config/dev.exs` looks like:

```
config :codsonline, Codsonline.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  username: System.get_env("DATA_DB_USER"),
  password: System.get_env("DATA_DB_PASS"),
  hostname: System.get_env("DATA_DB_HOST"),
  database: "app_dev",
  pool_size: 10
```

Psql is running locally.

I've also set the port `nanobox evar add dry-run PORT=8080`

I've seen some other questions on this issue, and some comments indicate I might need to change the port Postrges is running or, or at least change the config to port: 5432, although I'm unsure where I would do that.

Comment: Export env variables in your command.

Comment: such as `nanobox evar add dry-run PORT=8080` ?

Comment: change `DATA_DB_HOST` from localhost to your socket directory

Comment: @VaoTsun what would that do?

Comment: that should try connecting locally and thus supposedly use peer authentication. connection refused mean that probably you lack row for connection from localhost

Comment: ok, and what is my socket directory.  Sorry if that's a very basic question.